# CQ5 QueryBuilder Search Not Working as Expected (when property NOT present)

Tags: aem

I'm trying to produce a query that will return all pages under a path where a property is NOT present.

Effectively I want the query builder query that will produce the following xpath: `/jcr:root/content/site/my/path//element(*, cq:Page)[not(jcr:content/task/@finished)]`

For CQ 5.3 the 'exists' property doesn't seem to be present (according to the docs: http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.html), however it looks like I can use 'not', so I've tried the following two examples but neither work as I expect in query debugger:

## 1

```
path=/content/site/my/path
type=cq:Page
property=jcr:content/task/finished
property.operation=not
```

## 2

```
path=/content/site/my/path
type=cq:Page
property=jcr:content/task/finished
property.operation=not
property.value=true
```

I've also seen pages that suggest these should work, and I can't seem to see any hotfixes that would cover fixing this (assuming it isn't actually working correctly).

Can anyone offer a solution or point out where I'm going wrong?

Using CQ 5.3, upgraded to crx 2.2.

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I have a few resource that I hope help you:

- My blog post about query API options: http://itgumby.github.io/blog/2014/10/cq-queries-demystified/
- 6 Dimension's post about specific query examples: http://labs.sixdimensions.com/blog/2014-10-07/9-jcr-sql-2-queries-every-aem-dev-should-know/
- Adobe QueryBuilder documentation: http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/search/querybuilder-api.html

Non-empty SQL2 (From the 6D post):

```
SELECT * FROM [cq:PageContent] WHERE [jcr:title] IS NOT NULL
```

Which means you could convert that to `WHERE [jcr:title] IS NULL`

If using QueryBuilder predicates, the property generally won't exist (deleted from node) if it is false.  Please manually verify in your case using CRX-DE lite and examining the node & its properties.  If the property does exist, but its value is false, then:

```
path=/content/site/my/path
type=cq:Page
property=@jcr:content/task/finished
property.value=false
```

Answer (score 0):

For any still struggling, this is how you do it

```
path=/content/site/my/path
type=cq:Page
property=jcr:content/task/finished
property.operation=exists
property.value=false
```

Comment: Like I said, the exists operation doesn't seem to be present in version 5.3.